# How can I accept() multiple sockets using Overlapped IO?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, overlapped-io

I am having a problem understanding how can I accept multiple sockets (quickly) when using Overlapped IO (with Completion Routines).

So in my server this is the pseudo code:

```
while(true)
{
    sock = accept();
    WSARecv(sock, callback_function);
    Wait(); // need to make the calling thread alertable
}

callback_function()
{
    // process data here
}
```

So as you can see I can only accept one socket, and then I enter a wait state, and only when `sock` receive something that I will be able to accept another socket!

Comment: See AcceptEx() on MSDN.

Comment: Alternatively, use WSAAccept, which blocks via an alertable wait.  (That is, your callback functions will be executed; one catch is that you mustn't issue any blocking socket functions inside the callback function.)

Comment: Alternatively, use `WSAAsyncSelect()` or `WSAEventSelect()` to detect when a new client is pending before then calling `accept()`.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau You mean this way when a client is pending the `wait()` is "woken up" also (in addition for it being woken up when the callback function is called), which allows me to `accept()` without blocking and go back immediately to `wait()` ?

Comment: @user4592590: yes. They both allow you to receive an `FD_ACCEPT` notification when a new client connection is pending so you don't have to wait on a blocking `accept()`. In your example, you can use `WSAEventSelect()` with `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` with its `fAlertable` parameter set to true.